# Groupby and transpose in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I've got a table that looks like this:

[image]

I need it to look like this:

[image]

Note that I had many telephones for the same company split in different rows. I'd like to split it in columns.

Any idea?

Comment: What's the criteria for collapsing rows? For example, in your top table, you have three rows starting with `JCV INDUSTRIA`, however each has a different value in the column labeled `Nome`. At the same time, the rows starting with `IRMAOS DA R...` don't get collapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Google Sheet, I'd use `UNIQUE` to get a unique list of the values in the `Razão Social` column, then I'd use `FILTER` to get the list of numbers and `TRANSPOSE` to transform the column of results into a row of results.

Assuming that your example lives in A1:D12, then the following simple example should get you started:

In A13, put `=UNIQUE(A1:A12)`.

IN B13, put `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$8, $A$2:$A$8 = D2))`

Here's a sample sheet that shows a basic example in action:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1amSG6__0Zvk-vHg3aHS-LnBSxL8it6JRipQIffojGGM/edit

Comment: No worries, @abutremutante. You're very close. It's just that in some of your calls to `FILTER` you are using a range from the `final` sheet when you should be using a range from the `Resultado` sheet.Check out https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_crVWOksBHnO2VZeejAQA_qw7TKNmI3d3niAM2hgX-E/edit#gid=604803818 to see how it should look. Also, I added a call to `UNIQUE` to the formula to remove duplicate phone numbers.

Comment: eg. In your sample sheet, `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Resultado!B$2:B$770; A$2:A$770 = A8))` should actually be `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Resultado!B$2:B$770; Resultado!A$2:A$770 = A8))`

Comment: Outstanding! Did it!

Comment: Thanks! Glad to help :)